# What is correct way to define different keys for different mode like release and debug

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        buildTypes.each {

            it.buildConfigField 'String', 'GOOGLE_ANALYTIC_KEY', GoogleTracker_KEY_RELEASE
            it.buildConfigField 'String',  'PARSE_APPLICATION_ID', PARSE_RELEASE_APPLICATION_ID
            it.buildConfigField 'String',  'PARSE_CLIENT_ID', PARSE_RELEASE_CLIENT_ID
            it.buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'BRANCH_IO_MODE_IS_LIVE', BRANCH_IO_MODE_LIVE
        }
    }

    debug {
        versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

        buildTypes.each {
            it.buildConfigField 'String', 'GOOGLE_ANALYTIC_KEY', GoogleTracker_KEY_DEBUG
            it.buildConfigField 'String',  'PARSE_APPLICATION_ID', PARSE_DEBUG_APPLICATION_ID
            it.buildConfigField 'String',  'PARSE_CLIENT_ID', PARSE_DEBUG_CLIENT_ID
            it.buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'BRANCH_IO_MODE_IS_LIVE', BRANCH_IO_MODE_TEST
         }
    }
}
```

But it is not working and always generating debug keys even in release mode.
(All variable value i am providing from gradle.properties)

Comment: if you getting values from `gradle.properties` then it wont work.

Comment: Do it like  `it.buildConfigField 'String', 'GOOGLE_ANALYTIC_KEY', value` separately for both

Comment: Why it would not work from gradle.properties ? any specific reason ? How to achieve using gradle.properties ?

Comment: I don't know the reason. I tried by using `gradle.properties` i faced the same . You can ask this question to `Google developers`.

Comment: :) It picks but only debug one .. not release one .. What is happening inside dont know ??

Comment: I think it's becoz there is only one `gradle.properties`. and there is no separate `gradle.properties` file for different `build variants` so

Comment: But I am using two different keys from two different name like: GoogleTracker_KEY_RELEASE = "XXXXXXXX" GoogleTracker_KEY_DEBUG = "XXXXXXXX" and using these variable in different versions like release and debug

Comment: for that  [take a look](http://inaka.net/blog/2014/12/22/create-separate-production-and-staging-builds-in-android/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104175/discussion-between-lokesh-tiwari-and-m-d).

Answer (score -1):

It is mistake of **buildTypes.each** It is getting executed every-time and creating only one key for both debug of release(Either Debug key or Release key based on sequence written in build.gradle I think)
 
This is how I resolved this 
     Created two different type of build **buildTypes.debug** and **buildTypes.release**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
        minifyEnabled true
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    /*While app is in debug mode disable crashlytics*/
    debug {
        versionNameSuffix "-DEBUG"
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}

buildTypes.debug {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'GOOGLE_ANALYTIC_KEY', GoogleTracker_KEY_DEBUG
    it.buildConfigField 'String',  'PARSE_APPLICATION_ID', PARSE_DEBUG_APPLICATION_ID
    it.buildConfigField 'String',  'PARSE_CLIENT_ID', PARSE_DEBUG_CLIENT_ID
    it.buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'BRANCH_IO_MODE_IS_LIVE', BRANCH_IO_MODE_TEST
}

buildTypes.release {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'GOOGLE_ANALYTIC_KEY', GoogleTracker_KEY_RELEASE
    it.buildConfigField 'String',  'PARSE_APPLICATION_ID', PARSE_RELEASE_APPLICATION_ID
    it.buildConfigField 'String',  'PARSE_CLIENT_ID', PARSE_RELEASE_CLIENT_ID
    it.buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'BRANCH_IO_MODE_IS_LIVE', BRANCH_IO_MODE_LIVE
}
```